# AWS - How to get users MFA enabled/disabled value in JAVA using aws-java-sdk-iam?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, multi-factor-authentication

I have to get the AWS IAM users MFA value and create a report for MFA not enabled users.

I am able to get ListUsersResult object using AmazonIdentityManagementClient but I didn't find the MFA filed in ListUsersResult object.

```
ListUsersResult response = amazonidentitymanagmentclient.listUsers(request);
```

So how to get users MultiFactorAuth flag in **JAVA**.

Answer (score 0):

With AWS Java SDK v2.x, you can use `iamClient.listVirtualMFADevices()` and loop through the devices to find the one that's associated with your user.

`virtualMFADevice.user()` returns the `iam.model.User` associated with it.

So if you want to generate a report, you can build a `Map` of all MFA devices userId->MFA & when building your list just pick one from the `Map` if it exists.